# What calls are you making?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Sorry, if this is a trivial question. But I feel really confused when I ask people, their answers are different to my answer. So I want to ascertain what exactly is answered to this question.

For example: We have some kind of call (bank customer's call, mobile customer's call, Data base calls)  which we have to make. When I ask a question to one guy

> What calls you are making?

Should the answer be *in number of call* or *which call*?

Comment: I think you will need to add considerably more detail to your question; what type of 'calls', telephone calls? are you trading in financial instruments? are you hunting ducks? Provide an example of their answer and allow us to compare it to your answer perhaps.

Comment: Quintessence of severe formatting problems.

Comment: I think the answer to "what calls" is *which*. The answer to "how many" is *number*.

Comment: **What calls are you making?** is a grammatical question. What do you mean by: *their answer is different to my answer*? Can you give an example of "their answer"?

Comment: The answer which given by Mr Noah is correct. as far as i know. they reply in number of calls.

Comment: If you believe that @Noah's explanation to be the best, please award his answer.

Comment: And if you really want to ask a question, you should correct the title, which is not a question, and is ungrammatical.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It does improve the question a lot. Sadly, it also introduces new uncertainty, as neither "in number of call" nor "which call" make sense as an answer to "What calls you are making?", and indeed the former does not make sense *at all*. Please clarify further what it is you are really after. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Which calls are you making?** This presumes the calls are being made from a pre-determined list.

**How many calls are you making?** You do't need to ask this question if you ask the first one and get an answer.

**What calls are you making?** This question does not rely on the existence of the pre-determined list.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to questions, English seems to be very specific to some extent. If your question starts with the word *what* it means you want to know about something. On the first try, it could only mean to simply find some information about something. In the context you provided, it looks like that the questioner wants to know about the calls in general. It doesn't imply how many calls did you make. That said, it could mean *how many* if the question is based on previous information in the conversation. For example,

> He has three cars. What?